# Webcam video is black and white Python code

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to test the real time video through python code using my laptop webcam
the code i used so far is

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Media Feed',frame)
    
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code works fine but when webcam opens it shows the video like the image i have attached
and also after 3,4 seconds I get an exception on jupyternote book that **unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code**

Please let me know what should i do to get the clear video
Thanks[image: py]

Comment: Your code is fine, It must be some hardware or software issue, have you tried using python directly instead of jupyter notebook

Comment: @Ta946 Thanks for your response, yes i tried and the same thing is happening with direct python code

Comment: Have you tried if your webcam works fine with other applications?

Comment: @ai2ys No this is the first time I'm working with webcam

Comment: @WaseemKhan To exclude that the webcam might be defect, the easiest approach would be to use it with another application and check if it works alright.