# Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code python jupyternotebook

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to run cv2 .read() in python

Every time I run a simple code just to see myself from my webcam. It gives a strange error which I am not able to solve and I've almost searched a lot about it. I only want to capture my video through webcam.
My webcam is working fine as when I execute the code the code runs and opens a window and shows the image from webcam but the image is grey and it works only for a second or two. It immediately shows the error.
[image: webcam for 3 seconds opens like this]

This is my code which is probably fine according to me.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Media Feed',frame)
    
    if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Everytime I run this code it gives the following error :-

```
error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

After running the pip -V and pip list, the results are attached [pip -V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOd7w.png)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Comment: camera seems broken. tell us *everything* you know about the camera. oh, and remove those screenshots. post that text as text. you can copy text out of a terminal window.

Comment: What was changed from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641388/webcam-video-is-black-and-white-python-code)? "Have you tried if your webcam works fine with other applications?".

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing different older versions of opencv and 3.1.0 worked for me. I was using the latest version before and had the same problem, now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

I was in the same situation
[image]